# In Mongodb if nscannedObjects = total records in the collection does it mean full collection scan?

Tags: mongodb

Explain method gives me the following result

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor headers.From_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 83057,
    "nscannedObjects" : 120477,
    "nscanned" : 120477,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 120581,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 120581,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 250,
    "indexBounds" : {
    "headers.From" : [
        [
            {
                "$minElement" : 1
            },
            {
                "$maxElement" : 1
            }
        ]
    ]
    },
    "server" : "Andrews-iMac.local:27017"
}
```

I have 120477 records in my collection, does this mean my query performed full collection scan ??

any help is greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: Ah, another person taking the MongoDB developers class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it means that all documents were scanned.

- **83057** documents matched your query (`n`)
- **120477** documents were scanned (`nscanned` and `nscannedObjects`)

The [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain/#core-explain-output) explains the fields in the explain output.

The relevant pieces are here:

### explain.n

> n is a number that reflects the number of documents that match the
>   query selection criteria.

### explain.nscanned

> Specifies the total number of documents or index entries scanned
>   during the database operation. You want n and nscanned to be close in
>   value as possible. The nscanned value may be higher than the
>   nscannedObjects value, such as if the index covers a query. See
>   indexOnly.

Comment: In this query db.messages.find({'headers.Date':{'$gt': new Date(2001,3,1)}},{'headers.From':1, _id:0}).sort({'headers.From':1}) How to find out which stage that is find stage or sort stage is using index ?

Comment: @PraveenGr - Best to ask a new question. Then, you'll have room to include details of your schema, the query, all nicely formatted. :)

Comment: @PraveenGr if indexOnly is true it means it used the index for the scan. If scanAndOrder is false it means it used the index to sort

Comment: Hi - what is the difference between `nscannedAllPlans` and `nscannedObjects` ? If the value of the former is greater than  latter, then what does it mean? If I'm looking for a full collection scan, which one should I look for?

Comment: Index entries are included in the `nscannedAllPlans` and not in the other.